# Unable to Understand this Git functionality

Tags: git, github

I am newbie to GIT and my requirement is simple . I and my colleague are both working on automation framework on eclipse and i have a folder in local that has .git initialized.My colleague has a folder with .git initialized.

Now i have a common repository on github that i want both me and my colleague to push the work to different branches/ same branch and merge them and then pull from merged branch to our local repos , work on our local files and push again.

Now i dont understand how to do it , if me and my colleuague push to different branches then on remote it says we cant merge because they are unrelated commits.I am using compare option i dont know how to merge on remote.
If we push to same branch the last push is overriding.

I dont understand how to do the whole git thing . It will be really great help if someone can make me understand breifly. I dont have any seniors here so asking on stackoverflow.

My requirement again is just to update the origin with our individual work on same files and  pull from origin the latest code contaning both our work .

Advanced Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters. You should create a remote branch (normally) called `master` where you will push completely functional and robust code.

Then is recommended to create a remote branch called `next` where you will push functional code that can be improved. => This branch results from checking out `master`

Once you have this. Each collaborator can pull `next` and work on it (I think you didn't do this and that's why your branches are not related). => This means you have a local `next` branch.

It is recommended to leave the local `next` as an exact copy of the remote one. So I would recommend you to do `git checkout -b my_branch` and do your work in this branch.

Once you have functional code in `my_branch` you should push it to the remote branch `next`. => This way several people can do the same. => Therefore you can merge when necessary.

When you have something robust and you want to do a delivery, is a good practice to merge remote `next` and `master` . This way your `master` branch will contain the releases of your software.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan , but if we both push to remote next branch , wont the latest collaborator work override the previous one? How can we make sure both of our work on same files get updated .

Comment: @CodingGirl1 . That's where you have to be careful. First of all, before pushing you should make sure that your commit was merged (or rebased) with the very last version of `next` . This way you won't lose or overwrite anything. Once your commit was merged you can push it. Everyone should do this. So, after finishing your work in `my_branch` (you committed) , you should pull `next` again (so you have the most recent version in your local and then merge (I'd prefer rebase) . Then you do `git checkout my_branch` and `git rebase next` . This way you can make sure your branch has all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, you can't (easily) push from two unrelated projects to a single project.

Instead, one of you should start an empty project, and push that to the central repo; then the other dev should `git clone` that and start their work in the clone.

Each clone has information about what was pulled from the central repo and how it relates to earlier commits. This is crucial to Git's functionality for tracking commits, merges, branches, etc.

When you both attempt to push to a shared branch like `master`, Git will tell you what conflicts there are, and won't let you push until you sort them out.